# C# Reading strings from a file and finding matches between Start string and an End String different by one character

Tags: c#, string, comparison

Suppose I have a txt file with strings {ABAA, AAAA, ABZA, ABZZ, and AAZZ} and my Start word is AAAA and my end word is AAZZ.
I need to find all the words between the start word and end word different by one character; so from the example given my results would be: AAAA, ABZZ and AAZZ.

At the moment what I am doing is creating a list and reading the file line-by-line and passing it to the list.

```
    // 1 Declare new List.
   List<string> lines = new List<string>();

    // 2
    // Use using StreamReader for disposing.
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(PATH))
    {
        // 3
        // Use while != null pattern for loop
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            // 4
            // Insert logic here.
            // ...
            // "line" is a line in the file. Add it to our List.
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }
```

My question is: how do I look for strings different by one character? Do I need to break the string that I read from the file into characters and do a comparison to my Start and End Strings?

Comment: You should still clarify a few things. Does a 'line' contain multiple words? Separated by what?

Comment: And what exactly is the target function? Do the words have to be lexically _between_ Start and End? And 1-char different from what?

Comment: @Henk the line contains a single word

Comment: OK, now try to explain the constraints a little better. And add a few more examples. And why is ABAA not in the results?

Comment: @ Henk - the target function is to find words between the Start and End words. Yes, the words have to be lexically between Start and End words. And the 1-char different from the chars in the Start word.

Comment: @Henk - ABAA is not in the results because it is different by more than one letter.For example, if StartWord = Spin, EndWord = Spot and File file contains

Spin
Spit
Spat
Spot
Span

then Result should contain
Spin
Spit
Spot

Two examples of incorrect results:
Spin, Span, Spat, Spot    (invalid as it takes 3 changes rather than 2)
Spin, Spon, Spot          (invalid as spon is not a word)

Comment: And ABZZ is more than 1 char form the Start word. Think it over and try to spec it clearly.

Comment: I think in the first example, ABAA is invalid because it is before the start word. I.e. read all the words out of a file, ignore everything until the start word is hit, then start doing comparisons until the end word is hit and then ignore the rest. So the problem is basically solved with an algorithm that determines if a word differs by more than one character from another word. The rest is trivial.

Comment: @craigt: How are you  going to (trivially) eliminate 'spon' ?

Comment: Hehe, Henk, *I Think*... Im not sure man, these examples still have my head spinning, I just re read the one example and it completely blew my theory out of the water.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool compareStrings(a, b): return a.Zip(b, (a,b) => { a, b }).Where(x => x.a != x.b).Take(2).Count() <= 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are very good at finding this sort of thing and .NET has excellent support for regular expressions.  First you need to define the regular expression. 
Your requirements are a bit vague but according to your description, example data and example results I'm inferring that you want to match the start word and every word that varies from the end word by exactly one character. The regex you need is:

```
\bAAAA\b|\bAAZ\w\b|\bAA\wZ\b|\bA\wZZ\b|\b\wAZZ\b
```

Let me break that down for left to right.

- '\b' means "word boundary" which could be whitespace or a curly brace or other such non-word character.
- 'AAAA' is your start word and would be matched litterally
- '\b' means "word boundary"
- '|' means "alternation" which essentially means "match the expression on the left OR match the expression on the right"
- '\b' means "word boundary"
- 'AAZ\w' is the first permutation of one-character differences from your end word. '\w' means "any word character."
- '\b' means "word boundary"
- '\bAA\wZ\b' is the second permutation of one-character differences from your end word.
- '\bA\wZZ\b' is the third permutation.
- '\b\wAZZ\b' is the fourth and final permutation and would also match the end word.

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html for definitions of "word boundary" and "word character."

Now for the code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string pattern = @"\bAAAA\b|\bAAZ\w\b|\bAA\wZ\b|\bA\wZZ\b|\b\wAZZ\b";


// 1 Declare new List.
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

// 2
// Use using StreamReader for disposing.
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(PATH))
{
    // 3
    // Use while != null pattern for loop
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // 4
        if (Regex.IsMatch(line, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            // ...
            // "line" is a line in the file. Add it to our List.
            lines.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your regex correctly, but I think the "aaaa" and "bbbb" were just examples, the start and end words could be any words, or any length. Generating a pattern for any word might be a bit complex?

Comment: "aaaa" and "bbbb" are just examples, but requirements in the OP are vague: "find all words between start word & end word different by 1 char." In order to find a difference we need a reference for comparison and the OP didn't specify a reference. Based on OP's example I concluded the reference is the end word.

Generating the pattern should be easy. Look at the pattern I gave. It includes the start word plus every one character variation of the reference word (which I assumed to be end word.) Writing a for loop that would generate every one character variation for any given word would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of all the requirements, but this function should return the amount of characters that match between two words.

```
private int CheckWord(string startWord, string otherWord)
{
    List<char> start = new List<char>(startWord.ToArray());
    List<char> wordt = new List<char>(otherWord.ToArray());
    return start.Intersect(wordt).Count();
}
```

This call CheckWord("start", "srart"); returns 4. Match that number against the length of the string to determine how different they are.